# rqt_graph not shown in window

Tags: ros, rqt-graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,

I am new in ROS .

I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS .
ROS Hydro

I want to test the tuturial 6 about undrstanding ROS topics.

I can run the first command . but in part when I want to see the output of
rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph

in the opened window I can't see the map of rqt graph.

the opened window is empty but there are some button in it.

```
sara@sara:~$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph
Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible.
PluginHandlerDirect._restore_settings() plugin "rqt_graph/RosGraph#0" raised an exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 116, in _restore_settings
    self._plugin.restore_settings(plugin_settings_plugin, instance_settings_plugin)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 202, in restore_settings
    self._refresh_rosgraph()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 226, in _refresh_rosgraph
    self._update_graph_view(self._generate_dotcode())
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 259, in _update_graph_view self._redraw_graph_view()
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 292, in _redraw_graph_view same_label_siblings=True)
  File "/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_dotgraph/dot_to_qt.py", line 228, in dotcode_to_qt_items graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dotcode.encode("ascii", "ignore"))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pydot.py", line 199, in graph_from_dot_data
    return dot_parser.parse_dot_data(data)
NameError: global name 'dot_parser' is not defined
```

What should I do ?

Thanks in advance
Sarah

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132946/rqt_graph-not-shown-in-window/) by [sara.ershadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/12406/sara.ershadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Veerachart](https://answers.ros.org/users/5334/veerachart/) on 2014-03-03**:
I also got the same problem with you. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and ROS Hydro, installed from source a week ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know that this is an older topic and that there was an answer given.  But in my case that answer did NOT work.

I'm running indigo installed on Linux Mint 17.1 (based on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty).  I was having the same error as listed above and all the solutions I found didn't help.  Until I did some digging.

I found that due to having more than one Python version installed the pip that was running by default was updating a different version of Python than ROS was using.  So when I tried un-installing pyparsing and pydot and then installing newer versions there was no apparent change in behavior.

Trying to downgrade pyparsing gave an error and would not install the 1.5.7 version.

What I did find was that I had to explicitly run the version of pip from where the version of Python 2.7 being used by ROS was running on my system.

In my case this was
sudo /usr/bin/pip install --upgrade pydot
This caused pyparsing and pydot to be updated.  Note that I got a message about not uninstalling pydot due to it being owned by OS, but this didn't impact the fix

Once the update completed rqt_graph is now working on my system.

You can do:
which python
To locate the directory where python is running from and double check where your pip is by doing:
which pip

Both pip and python should be on the same path (e.g. /usr/bin in my case) but the default pip binary was being found at /usr/local/bin and not /usr/bin.

So I thought I would add this note for anyone who happens to be tearing their hair out with a similar issue.

Burt

---

Originally posted by [burtbick](https://answers.ros.org/users/30032/burtbick/) with karma: 201 on 2017-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951748/pydot-and-graphviz-error-couldnt-import-dot-parser-loading-of-dot-files-will and tried according to the top comment. It works! (You may need to add sudo.)

Hope it also works with yours. (I cannot post to answer.)

---

Originally posted by [Veerachart](https://answers.ros.org/users/5334/veerachart/) with karma: 86 on 2014-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Veerachart](https://answers.ros.org/users/5334/veerachart/) on 2014-03-06**:
In case you did not install by pip, try "sudo apt-get remove python-pyparsing".

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-03-31**:
Hi @Veerachart can you give all steps you used to resolve the problem? I'm also using Ubuntu 13.10 with Hydro. Thanks!

**Comment by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on 2014-04-01**:
Never mind: just follow the top comment (1. $ sudo pip uninstall pyparsing 2. $ sudo pip install -Iv https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyparsing/pyparsing-1.5.7.tar.gz#md5=9be0fcdcc595199c646ab317c1d9a709 3. $ pip install pydot)

**Comment by [LikeSmith](https://answers.ros.org/users/18041/likesmith/) on 2016-04-25**:
I am having the same issue as above, and I tried to do this, but pip stopped working after i uninstalled pyparsing.